# data frame or matrix of quantiles

Tags: r, matrix, quantile, statistics-bootstrap

I used following code to get the quantiles (25 %, 50 %,75 % and 99 %) of x and replicate 100 times.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,5,4,5,6,7,8,5,4,3,2)
sample.boot=numeric()

for (i in 1:100){
       sample.boot[i]<-quantile(sample(x,replace = T),c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))
}
sample.boot
```

This is not giving desired output.  I want all four quantiles replicated 100 times and stored as data frame or in a matrix as below.

```
4 5 5 7
2 4 6 7
.......
.......
3 5 5 6
```

Comment: you should take a look at the warnings produced, they explain what happens : you're trying to put as i-th value of your vector, a vector of length 4, it cannot work.

Comment: You don't need the outside loop `t(replicate(100, quantile(sample(x,replace = T),c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))))`

Comment: I know. I edited that the outside loop is unnecessary

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t(replicate(100, quantile(sample(x,replace = T),c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))))
#        25% 50% 75%  99%
#   [1,]   3   4   5 7.64
#   [2,]   5   5   5 7.00
#   [3,]   2   5   5 7.88
#   [4,]   2   4   5 7.88
#   [5,]   4   5   7 7.88
#   [6,]   4   4   7 7.88
#   [7,]   3   4   5 7.00
#   [8,]   2   4   5 7.00
#   [9,]   4   5   5 7.76
#  [10,]   3   4   5 7.64
```

Internally `replicate` uses `sapply` and does so in a way that makes this type of repeated action efficient. The first argument accepts an integer value representing the number of times that the second argument should be repeated.

The entire function is wrapped with `t(..)`. This arranges the output with quantiles  as columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `rowQuantiles` from `library(matrixStats)` after we `sample` one time with length equal to `length(x)*100` and convert the `vector` into a `matrix` of dimensions `100*length(x)`

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 <- matrix(sample(x, 100*length(x), replace=TRUE), nrow=100, byrow=TRUE)
rowQuantiles(m1, probs=c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))
```

Checking whether we get the same output as `replicate`

```
set.seed(24)
r1 <- t(replicate(100, quantile(sample(x,replace = T),c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))))
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(x, 100*length(x), replace=TRUE), nrow=100, byrow=TRUE) 
r2 <- rowQuantiles(m1, probs=c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.99))
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or we get the `sample` of 'x' with length specified as in the previous case, create a grouping variable using `rep`, and then use standard aggregate by group to get the `quantile`.  Here we  can use `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
d1 <-data.table(V1=sample(x, 100*length(x), replace=TRUE), 
                V2=rep(1:100,each=length(x)))[, 
      as.list(quantile(V1, probs=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75,0.99))), by = V2]
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. did not know about this package.

Comment: @Alph It's a useful package.  I find some of the functions in the package to very efficient.  Though, I haven't done the benchmarks, I guess it would be efficient as we are `sampling` only once and then do the `rowQuantiles`.

Comment: my idea was to calculate quantiles using different samples (using sample function with replacement) and see the distribution of  the each quantiles

Comment: @Alph If you check the output of both methods, they are `identical`

Comment: @ akrun, I saw that.  I appreciate  your help.